# Is a flask config file persistent?

Tags: python, flask

If I create a variable in a Flask config file, will the actual config file be updated when I update the variable in the app?

Comment: Not unless you program it to edit the config file on change of variable. Otherwise the update should be transient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The config file is read once, and never written to.  If you change the file, or change the config, you will need to read or write those changes yourself.

This is trivial to verify by making a change and viewing the file afterwards.

Reading config from a file is just one way you can configure your app, and Flask doesn't try to provide an api for writing back to arbitrary config sources.